# Call method from Object within Object?(Java)

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods

Ive tried searching and reading trough (similar sounding) problems, but I cant seem to find a solution.

I am currently making a prototype to control some lamps with a text input.
The text input is already working and it can correctly filter trough the inputs and only pick out the relevant parts.

Anyway, for that to be usefull now I need to first create Objects of my House, which contain all floors, which contain all rooms, which contains all actors(Lamps etc.).

These are the snippets for all those Objects, from top to bottom as theyre supposed to be stacke inside eachother(The code isnt finished yet nor optimized, I know I can use switch-case for all the if-else statements):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Building {
    String Name;
    ArrayList<floor> floor = new ArrayList<floor>();

    public Building(String Name){
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public boolean checkFloor(String Name){
        int count = floor.size();
        boolean ret = false;
        while(count < floor.size()){
            if (floor.get(count).Name == Name){
                count = floor.size();
                ret = true;
            }
            count++;
        }        
        return(ret);
    }

    public void newFloor(String Name){
        Name = Name.toLowerCase();
        if (Name == "keller" || Name == "basement"){
            floor basement = new floor("basement");
            floor.add(basement);
        }
        else if (Name == "eg"){
            floor ground = new floor("eg");
            floor.add(ground);
        }
        else if (Name == "1og"){
            floor first = new floor("first");
            floor.add(first);
        }
        else if (Name == "2og"){
            floor second = new floor("second");
            floor.add(second);
        }
        else if (Name == "3og"){
            floor third = new floor("third");
            floor.add(third);
        }    
            }    
    public void newRoom(String Floor, String Name){        
    }

}
```

---

```
    public class floor {
    String Name;
    ArrayList<room> room = new ArrayList<room>();
    transcoder transcode = new transcoder();

    public floor(String Name){
        this.Name = Name;
    }



    public boolean checkRoom(String Name){
        int count = room.size();
        boolean ret = false;
        while(count < room.size()){
            if (room.get(count).Name == Name){
                count = room.size();
                ret = true;
            }
            count++;
        }

        return(ret);
    }

    public void newRoom(String mName){
        String Name = transcode.getRoom(mName);
        if( Name == "ground"){
            room ground = new room("ground");
            room.add(ground);
        }
        else if ( Name == "basement"){
            room basement = new room("basement");
            room.add(basement);
        }
        else if ( Name == "first"){
            room first = new room("first");
            room.add(first);
        }
        else if ( Name == "second"){
            room second = new room("second");
            room.add(second);
        }      
    }
}
```

---

```
public class room {
    String Name;
    ArrayList<Actor> Actors = new ArrayList<Actor>();

    public room(String Name){
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void addActor(String Name, int Type, String Address, int Channel, boolean Dim){
        Actors.add(new Actor(Name, Type, Address, Channel, Dim));
    }

    public void removeActor(String Name){
        int count = 0;
        while (count <= Actors.size()){
           if (Actors.get(count).Name == Name){
               Actors.remove(count);
               count = Actors.size();
           }
           count++;
        }
    }

    public boolean containsActor(String Name){
        int count = 0;
        boolean ret = false;
        while (count < Actors.size()){

                if (Actors.get(count).Name == Name){
                    ret = true;
                    count = Actors.size();
                }
                count++;
            }
        return(ret);
    }

    public String getAddress(String Name){
        int count = 0;
        String ret = "leer";
        while (count < Actors.size()){
            if (Actors.get(count).Name == Name){
                ret = Actors.get(count).Address;
                count = Actors.size();
            }
            count++;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    public int getType(String Name){
        int count = 0;
        int ret = 0;
        while (count < Actors.size()){
            if (Actors.get(count).Name == Name){
                ret = Actors.get(count).Type;
                count = Actors.size();
            }
            count++;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Actor {
    String Name;
    String Address;
    int Channel;
    int Type;
    boolean Dim;
    int On; //muss noch deklariert werden!
    int Off;


    public Actor(String Name, int Type, String Address, int Channel, boolean Dim){
       this.Name = Name;
       this.Type = Type;
       this.Address = Address;
       this.Channel = Channel;
       this.Dim = Dim;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do now in my Mainclass, is to create a new Building with a floor, room and some actors. The code goes as follow:

```
System.out.println("Gebäudename eingeben(egal): ");
String Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building Building = new Building(Name);
System.out.println("Stockname eingeben(eg): ");
Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building.newFloor(Name);
System.out.println("Raumname eingeben(wohnen): ");
Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building.floor
```

Now at the end at Building.floor, I dont quite see how I can now add a new Room to the object floor. Id appreciate any help, as Im not quite that fancy with Java yet and probably am missing an obvious part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the simplest way to add new room to the floor of the building is thus:

`Building.floor.get(0).newRoom(Name);`

`floor` is an ArrayList and calling `get()` on the first index will allow you to then call `newRoom()`.

Some suggestions to make your code more readable/understandable:

- Capitalize your class names by changing `floor` to `Floor` and `room` to `Room`.
- Change the name of your `ArrayList` from `floor` to `floors`.
- Change the name of your `ArrayList` from `room` to `rooms`.
- Declare separate `String` variables in your main class for storing user input.
- Store your objects separately before adding to the appropriate `ArrayList`.

The most crucial thing I would say to add is a `getFloor()` method to your `Building` class.

like this (assuming you make the above changes):

```
public Floor getFloor(String floorName){
    Floor correctFloor = null;
    for(Floor floor : floors) {
        if(floor.Name == floorName) {
            correctFloor = floor;
        }
    }
    return correctFloor;
}
```

Then you instead of

```
System.out.println("Gebäudename eingeben(egal): ");
String Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building Building = new Building(Name);
System.out.println("Stockname eingeben(eg): ");
Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building.newFloor(Name);
System.out.println("Raumname eingeben(wohnen): ");
Name = user_input.nextLine();
Building.floor.get(0).newRoom(Name);
```

you can put (again assuming the above changes)

```
System.out.println("Gebäudename eingeben(egal): ");
String buildingName = user_input.nextLine();
Building building = new Building(buildingName);
System.out.println("Stockname eingeben(eg): ");
String floorName = user_input.nextLine();
Floor floor = new Floor(floorName);
building.newFloor(floorName);
System.out.println("Raumname eingeben(wohnen): ");
String roomName = user_input.nextLine();
building.getFloor(floorName).newRoom(roomName);
```

These are just suggestions and there are many ways you could do it~ Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, that works. Thanks for the formatting tips, will do them. The only reason I dont have a getFloor Method as of right now is because Im not quite done, I am constantly prototyping(thats why the code in the main method looks as it does right now, its just for quick testing).

Ill report back when Im further ahead! :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

In your Building class, make use of getters and setters. You have a `floor` variable but don't have any way to get it. Add this getter method to `Building`

```
public ArrayList<floor> getFloors(){
        return floor;
    }
```

Then in instead of saying `Building.floor` you can say something like

```
int floorToGet = (what ever floor in the ArrayList you want);
Building.getFloors.get(floorToGet).newRoom("New Room Name");
```

Also if I were to make a couple suggestion about your coding style and also some advice. By convention all classes start with upper case, i.e. `Building` as opposed to `building` you do this in some classes but not others. Also if you are wanting use syntax like `Building.floor` it's a good idea to make that variable `static`. Otherwise make getters/setters for the variables and instantiate a new object of building. And also by convention, variable names start lower case, i.e. in this case `Building building = new Building()`, what you have at first looks like your accessing a static variable that actually is not static.

One last suggestion if your familiar with this concept. It might make data access more easy if you subclass out some of your classes. And what I mean is, Buildings contain Floors, and Floors contain Rooms. So if it's not confusing, `Building` would be your main class, and then `Floors extends Building`, and `Room extends Floor`.

Just from a logical stand point I think that makes more sense. But hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.
(goddamit enter automaticly posts my answer!)

I do have Building, Floor etc. as separate classes. They just dont extend eachother. Would that be needed? 

What I am doing is basicly a text input like "Turn the wallamp in the kitchen on", of which it filters everything except "wallamp" "kitchen" "on", and then he looks for the address of the "wallamp" in "kitchen", and sends a TCP packet to turn the lamp on.

Comment: Needed? No. You can do it the way you are doing. My inner logistics just couldn't help but make that suggestion. If this is something you plan on maintaining (code wise) subclassing could clean it up. But if your just throwing this together and then wanting to forget about it once it's going, then probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I see. So I guess performance wise it wouldnt make a difference?
Thats my biggest concern.
And no I do plan on making this an ongoing Project.

Comment: No, I don't think performance is noticeably impacted one way or the other. But if this is an ongoing project, self-documenting/ maintainable code is going to be the way to go. Edit: That's just my opinion though.